# Expanding expression in differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I don't understand how they came up with the following answer in answer sheet.

```
f(x,y) ∈ C

u = x
v = y/x

df/dx = df/du - y/x^2 * (df/du) 
df/dy = 1/x * (df/dv)
```

This means:

```
d/dx = d/du - y/x^2 * d/dv 
d/dy = 1/x * d/dv
```

So far I understand everything. However now I want to expand the following expression, and this is where I feel I'm lost:

```
d^2*f/dxdy = d/dx(df/dy) = d/dx(1/x * df/dv) = -1/x^2 * df/dv + 1/x *d/dx * (df/dv) = ...
```

The last step is where I feel lost. How can they expand the expression to that? It feels like they are doing several things but not writing them out so therefore I can't figure out how it's possible.

Comment: Please, add some details. $f$ depends on x?y? Who are u and v? Also, please edit everything in latex, it makes it so much easier to read

Comment: I don't know how to do latex, but I fixed the rest. :)

Comment: To use Latex simply put `$` symbols around the math. Use the `\frac{}{}` command for fractions. `^` for exponents and `_` for indexes. For example you can write `$$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} - \frac{y}{x^2} \frac{df}{du}$$` to write  $$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} - \frac{y}{x^2} \frac{df}{du}$$